# Division between scalar and matrix in octave

Tags: octave

I am using octave and when I am writing this:

```
1/[1;2;3]
```

It returns the result as this:

```
ans = 0.071429   0.142857   0.214286
```

I can't understand this behavior, although I know the difference between '/' and './'.
I know './' refers to element wise division but how is '/' working in this case.

Comment: $1,2,3/\sqrt{1^2+2^2+3^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the 'matrix' is not square, the inverse is not defined. In that case, Octave uses the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse), which in this case is given by $\frac{1}{14}\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: The $/$-operator always solves a linear system and does not compute any inverses. While this is the same in exact arithmetic, there are differences in the stability. The same reason you should never use $x=A^{-1}b$ to solve $Ax=b$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though I really need to know why only square matrices have inverse and what are pseudo-inverse matrices, but I will study about those on my own now. Just needed a way.

Answer (score 2):

$1/[1;2;3]$ solves the system $x \cdot [1;2;3] = 1$ in the least-square sense.